# Why is the arima function giving odd answers

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima

I have a problem in interpreting what the `arima` function in R is doing.  I have the following code:

```
x <- 1000*.8^(0:100)
arima(x, order = c(1,0,0), include.mean = F)
```

The resulting coefficient is "0.9988".  But I would think the coefficient should be exactly "0.8", since `x[t] = 0.8 * x[t-1]`.

I must be missing something that R is doing in processing the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

**New Info I:**
If I change the function to

```
arima(x, order = c(1,0,0), include.mean = F, method="CSS")
```

then it solves for the correct coefficient of 0.8.

My problem that I am generally finding that the function `arima` with `order = c(1,0,0)` is often producing different results to:

```
lm(x[-1] ~ I(x[-length(x)]))
```

for all sorts of different time series that I am reviewing.

**New Info II:**
Some of the comments and answers below are concerned that there is no random fluctuation in my data.  I did this to make the problem as simple as possible, but even if you add in random fluctuation, `arima` still produces the same wrong results in the default case.  To add insult to injury, `arima` will sometimes get the right answer if you change `method = "CSS"`. This suggest that there is perhaps a computational issue with `arima` and not my misunderstanding the statistical model. Here is an extended set of two examples that highlight the problem (I ignore the intercept difference between `lm` and `arima` as these two items are not the same thing, but the coefficients should be.

```
set.seed(1)
# Example 2
x <- rep(1000,200)
for (i in 2:200) x[i]=x[i-1]*.8 + runif(1)*100 
plot(x,type="l")
arima(x, order = c(1,0,0))  #Incorrect answer:  coefficient = 0.9944
arima(x, order = c(1,0,0), method="CSS") # correct answer: coefficient = 0.7915
lm(x[-1] ~ I(x[-length(x)])) # correct answer: coefficient = 0.7914

# Example 3
x <- rep(0,200)
for (i in 2:200) x[i]=x[i-1]*.8 + runif(1)*.2 
plot(x,type="l")
arima(x, order = c(1,0,0))  #Incorrect answer:  coefficient = 0.8836
arima(x, order = c(1,0,0), method="CSS") # correct answer: coefficient = 0.8158
lm(x[-1] ~ I(x[-length(x)])) # correct answer: coefficient = 0.8158
```

Comment: Plot the residuals.  For that matter, plot `x`: does it look stationary?

Comment: I added some more information above, but I would think the arima function should solve for the coefficients whether or not the process is stationary. I have read the help on the function, and it does mention transforming the parameters, but provides no details as to what that transformation should be.

Comment: @howard123 What makes you think that if you have the perfect relationship x[t] = 0.8*x[t-1] that you get a correlation of .8 instead of 1?

Comment: According to the documentation, the arima function should solve for the coefficients in the equation`X[t] = a[1]X[t-1] + …' The coefficients are not the same as the correlation.

Comment: No random fluctuation has nothing to do with what @stats responded. The key is that your data should fluctuate around zero also known as stationary as a condition to apply arima.

Answer (score 5):

You need to read more about properties of an AR(1) model such as its mean and variance. So first see Example 1 in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model). You can see that the mean of an AR(1) becomes zero if $\mu=0$, which is your case. Right? So this means that your time series should fluctuate around zero if it is coming from an AR(1) with a zero mean. Now lets look at your generated `x`

```
x <- 1000*.8^(0:100)
ts.plot(x)
```

[image]

As you can see, before time 20, it is not alternating around zero! Therefore, you should NOT expect to see a coefficient of .8 even if you fit it with an `arima` function. R does not check whether it makes sense to fit an AR(1) to your data or not. Basically, this is your job! To do it correctly, first you need to simulated an AR(1) time series of data as follow:

```
> z=arima.sim(n = 101, list(ar = c(0.8)))
> ts.plot(z)
```

[image]

As you see, right now it is now almost mean stationary. So let's try an `arima` function on `z`

```
> arima(z, order = c(1,0,0),include.mean =FALSE)
Series: z 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean     

Coefficients:
         ar1
      0.7922
s.e.  0.0612

sigma^2 estimated as 1.175:  log likelihood=-151.96
AIC=307.93   AICc=308.05   BIC=313.16
```

Now the AR coefficient is correctly estimated as 0.7922 ... Cheers!

Comment: Stat:  Thank you for this detailed response.  However, even if I add random noise beyond point 20, arima fails to solve the model correctly.  I expanded my question above to include such examples.

Comment: @howard123 as stat points out it is important that your data to fluctuate around 0 for arima to work, once you do that in your simulation, you can be sure to get the answer you are expecting.

Comment: @howard123 Noise must be centred around zero by definition! $ E(w_t) = 0 $. Sometimes, it's even assumed to be Gaussian.